# Smoothly increase interval time with JS

Tags: javascript

How can i play a sound at an interval (for example once every second) and **gradually decrease the time between the intervals**?

At the moment, i use two intervals with setInterval, the first one plays the sound each second, the second setInterval speeds up the first interval every 20 seconds. This works, **but it leaves a nasty "pause" between the intervals**.

Is there a better way?

---

Example code (just to clarify, not necessary to read):

```
var audio = new Audio('track.wav');
var baseSpeed = 1000;
var myInt;
var changeInt;

//Starts a Run
function beatInterval() {
    audio.play();
};

//Speeds up the other interval
function speedUpInterval() {
    baseSpeed = baseSpeed - 20
    clearInterval(myInt);
    myInt = setInterval(beatInterval, baseSpeed);
    console.log(baseSpeed);


myInt = setInterval(beatInterval, baseSpeed);
changeInt = setInterval(speedUpInterval, 20000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can delay adjustment of speed, until interval function is actually executed:

```
var speedChanged = false;
function beatInterval() {
    if(speedChanged) {
        speedChanged = false;
        clearInterval(myInt);
        myInt = setInterval(beatInterval, baseSpeed);
    }
    audio.play();
};

function speedUpInterval() {
    baseSpeed = baseSpeed - 20
    speedChanged = true;
    console.log(baseSpeed);
}
```

Comment: Can you update your code and set speedChanged back to false in the if-statement for future reference?